# space between divs when using text-align

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I used `text-align: center` to to position three divs. But there is a small gap between each and every div. Why is it so? the picture is giving below? The divs are displayed as `inline-block`.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPKJ4.png]

Comment: use margin:0 and padding:0 to img tag

Comment: Without seeing your HTML+CSS code, it could be multiple things.

Comment: Are you using this image for background?

Answer (score 2):

Inline-block elements often have spaces in between them because HTML displays newlines in the code as a space character.

For example, this will have a space between each div:

```
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah...</div>
<div>blahblah...</div>
```

There are various workarounds for this such as getting rid of the space in your code:

```
<div>blah</div><div>blah...</div><div>blahblah...</div>
```

Or setting the parent element to `font-size: 0` and then setting the child divs to whatever font size you want.

I personally thought this was an interesting post on the subject: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: I've actually run into this problem myself beforehand and tried several of those techniques to fix it. I read that same post I linked months ago. I didn't mean to duplicate anyone's answers here. I apologize if I did. It wasn't intended.

Answer (score 1):

If the `div` elements are `inline-block` display, then the reason there are spaces in-between them is because it is recognizing all the new lines and spaces between the `div` elements and trimming them down to one space character. That is the space you are seeing.

You can solve this by using `float: left;` if that is applicable to your situation. Of course, you  may have to confine them to their own [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) due to the floats.

Another solution would be to get rid of the new lines and spaces in-between the `div` elements. You can do that like so:

**HTML:**

```
<div><img src="picture.jpg"></div
><div><img src="picture.jpg"></div
><div><img src="picture.jpg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you absolutely have to use `display: inline-block;` then refer to the link at the bottom of my answer for a wide range of solutions.

The best solution would be to change `display: inline-block;` to `float: left;` since they will float right next to each other by default.

If they are `inline-block` you will need to add `margin-right: -4px` to offset the default `margin-right`.

This is based from the lack of `HTML`/`CSS` from your question.

Here are a few options of dealing with `inline-blocks` default margin, [CSS-Tricks Inline-block](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: Not a good solution, I am sure he is using `inline-block` but using `-4px` is not a perfect solution.. I will let you know why...

Comment: yes, it worked. but is this value -4px hardcoded or what? is it always -4px?

Comment: Oh I know it's not a perfect solution and that is why I added the other options.

Comment: @user2957214 It is always a default 4px right margin on an `inline-block` element. Also - margins, padding, left, top, right, and bottom are somewhat frowned on unless you absolutely need to.

Comment: even after increasing the negetive value, ie -4 -8 -16...., i'm getting the same as it was for -4px.

Comment: @user2957214 it is because of the white space, make all the inline block elements on a single line in your source code and see, you wwillget rid of white space, perfect solution is to use float as already mentioned in the answer or use `font-size: 0` on the parent element..also, you can get rid of white space if you make the inline block elements in a single line in your source.. but that will be messy so go for other options, also, increasing the font ssizewill result in breaking the -4px rule..

Comment: cool, i crosschecked the same with my naked eye (since i dont have that much pixel density). u were right, Josh. 4px margin is there.

Comment: Yeah it is based on the space between them like SombreErmine has stated and there is a few ways to deal with it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QxHNa/ using -4px breaks.. while this wont http://jsfiddle.net/QxHNa/1/

Comment: I am not suggesting to use -4px so I will revise my answer.

Comment: @JoshPowell I used to suggest that too, and nah op asked me why so I am showing him why not to use, else I have mentioned in my previous comment that as josh answered,  youcan go for float too :)